# how to call table data from one view controller to another via didselect row at indexpath method

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to perform didselecterowatindexpath method please let me know how to call second  viewcontroller from first view controller using below method and passing the data to other view controller :

**My code is**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
pun=[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSLog(@"PUN IS :%@",pun);
     appDelegate.matri=pun;
     NSLog(@"matriC:%@",appDelegate.matri);
     SecViewController *SecView = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecView animated:YES ];
```

Comment: What result are you getting with this code?

Comment: what is the problem with this code.....

Comment: u have add the navigation controller in Appdelegate.M

Comment: i used appDelegate=(MainAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate ];
 in my viedidload but i dont want to use this

Comment: Mr. you are already calling second viewcontroller from first view controller, what you want is not clear here

Comment: what the error u get in the console

Comment: This is correct, from the second viewcontroller just read the data that you have set in your app delegate.

Comment: no its not give error bt actually i want call secview via creating simple obj of secviewcontroller

Comment: I suggest reading about UINavigationController and presentModalViewController:animated:, they helped you.

Comment: Is the current viewController embedded in a NavigationController?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. its a best option.
In your .h file create a method

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil Yourvariable:(yourdatatype *)variable Yourvariablex:(yourdatatype *)variablex bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

and in your .m file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil Yourvariable:(yourdatatype *)variable Yourvariablex:(yourdatatype *)variablex bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        //assign or use data here.

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mate follow below steps :

1. Goto SecViewController.h file and create a property of NSMutableArray.

   `@property(retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *newArray;`
2. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method write

   `SecViewController *secView = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
   secView.newArray = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secView animated:YES ];`
3. In SecViewController print the below line in `viewDidLoad` Method

   `NSLog(@"%@",newArray);`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 NSString *tempString =[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
 NSLog(@"PUN IS :%@", tempString);
 SecViewController *SecView = [[SecViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecViewController" bundle:nil];
 SecView.usernameString= tempString;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecView animated:YES ];
 }

//  .h file of SecViewController
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *usernameString;
@end

// .m file of SecViewController

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecViewController ()
{

}
@end

@implementation SecViewController
@synthesize usernameString;
```

Comment: in the above expamle usernameString is a string if you want to carry int/Array/Dictionary/.. declare that data type with property in secondviewcontroller.